# how to put horizontal scroll in a fluid DIv with a table inside

Tags: html, css, scroll, fluid

I have a fluid div with a table inside and a square inside each TD and I want to put a horizontal scroll bar in it. I have several problems:

1. The scroll bar doesn't show;
2. the elements inside the td class become distort.
3. When i resize the window browser, the elements and the div are outside the width.

I need help. Anyone?
Here's my code.
Thanks

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style media="all">
body {
    background: #F0F0F0;
}
.container, .wrap {
    position: relative;
    max-width: 800px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

#fixed-Left {
    width: 30px;
    height: auto;
    background: #fff;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}
.filas {
    display: block;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 11px;
    color: #333;
}
.filas ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 10px;
    list-style: none;
    font-size: 12px;
    height: auto;
}
.filas ul li {
    height: 16px;
    font-weight: bold;
    list-style: none;
}
#faded-Left {
    width: 20px;
    height: 100px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 30px;
    /* IE9 SVG, needs conditional override of 'filter' to 'none' */
    background: url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,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);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(left, rgba(255,255,255,1) 0%, rgba(255,255,255,0) 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right top, color-stop(0%, rgba(255,255,255,1)), color-stop(100%, rgba(255,255,255,0))); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, rgba(255,255,255,1) 0%, rgba(255,255,255,0) 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(left, rgba(255,255,255,1) 0%, rgba(255,255,255,0) 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(left, rgba(255,255,255,1) 0%, rgba(255,255,255,0) 100%); /* IE10+ */
    background: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(255,255,255,1) 0%, rgba(255,255,255,0) 100%); /* W3C */
 filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#ffffff', endColorstr='#00ffffff', GradientType=1 ); /* IE6-8 */
}
#fixed-Right {
    width: 30px;
    height: auto;
    background: #fff;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
}
#faded-Right {
    width: 20px;
    height: 100px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 30px;
    /* IE9 SVG, needs conditional override of 'filter' to 'none' */
    background: url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,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);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(right, rgba(255,255,255,1) 0%, rgba(255,255,255,0) 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, right top, right top, color-stop(0%, rgba(255,255,255,1)), color-stop(100%, rgba(255,255,255,0))); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(right, rgba(255,255,255,1) 0%, rgba(255,255,255,0) 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(right, rgba(255,255,255,1) 0%, rgba(255,255,255,0) 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(right, rgba(255,255,255,1) 0%, rgba(255,255,255,0) 100%); /* IE10+ */
    background: linear-gradient(to left, rgba(255,255,255,1) 0%, rgba(255,255,255,0) 100%); /* W3C */
 filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#ffffff', endColorstr='#00ffffff', GradientType=1 ); /* IE6-8 */
}

.fluid {
    height: 340px;
    background: #fff;
    margin-left: 30px;
    width: 740px;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}

.cadeiras {
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    padding-top:7px;

}
tr.rowCadeiras{
    width:20px;
    padding:30px;
}

.imgRelvado {
    width: 100%;
    height: 40px;
    line-height: 40px;
    background: #04b46b;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.seat {
    height: 11px !important;
    width: 11px !important;
    font-size: 9px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
    -moz-border-radius: 3px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    text-shadow: none!important;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.seatAvail {
    background: #05cd7a;
    color: #000;
}
.seatTaken {
    background: #dbdbdb;
    color: #000;
    border: 1px solid #333333;
}
.seatReserv {
    background: #858585;
    color: #000;
    border: 1px solid #5b5b5b;
}
.seatSelect {
    background: #f5c226;
    color: #000;
    border: 1px solid #333333;
}

</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="wrap">
<div class="imgRelvado">Relvado</div>
<div class="container">
  <div id="fixed-Left">
    <div class="filas">
      <ul>
        <li>10</li>
        <li>11</li>
        <li>12</li>
        <li>13</li>
        <li>14</li>
        <li>15</li>
        <li>16</li>
        <li>17</li>
        <li>18</li>
        <li>19</li>
        <li>20</li>
        <li>21</li>
        <li>22</li>
        <li>23</li>
        <li>24</li>
        <li>25</li>
        <li>26</li>
        <li>27</li>
        <li>28</li>
        <li>29</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="faded-Left"></div>
  <div class="fluid">
  <div class="cadeiras">
      <table>
        <tr class="rowCadeiras">
          <td class="seat seatAvail"></td>
          <td class="seat seatAvail"></td>
          <td class="seat seatAvail"></td>
          <td class="seat seatAvail"></td>
          <td class="seat seatAvail"></td>
          <td class="seat seatAvail"></td>
          <td class="seat seatAvail"></td>
          <td class="seat seatAvail"></td>
          <td class="seat seatAvail"></td>
          <td class="seat seatAvail"></td>
          <td class="seat seatAvail"></td>
          <td class="seat seatAvail"></td>
          <td class="seat seatAvail"></td>
          <td class="seat seatAvail"></td>
          <td class="seat seatAvail"></td>
          <td class="seat seatAvail"></td> 
          <td class="seat seatAvail"></td>
          <td class="seat seatAvail"></td>
          <td class="seat seatAvail"></td>
          <td class="seat seatAvail"></td>
          <td class="seat seatAvail"></td>
          <td class="seat seatAvail"></td>
          <td class="seat seatAvail"></td>
          <td class="seat seatAvail"></td>
          <td class="seat seatAvail"></td>
          <td class="seat seatAvail"></td>
          <td class="seat seatAvail"></td>
          <td class="seat seatAvail"></td>
          <td class="seat seatAvail"></td>
          <td class="seat seatAvail"></td>
          <td class="seat seatAvail"></td>
          <td class="seat seatAvail"></td>
          <td class="seat seatAvail"></td>
          <td class="seat seatAvail"></td>
          <td class="seat seatAvail"></td>
          <td class="seat seatAvail"></td>
          <td class="seat seatAvail"></td>
          <td class="seat seatAvail"></td>
          <td class="seat seatAvail"></td>
          <td class="seat seatAvail"></td>
          <td class="seat seatAvail"></td>
          <td class="seat seatAvail"></td>
          <td class="seat seatAvail"></td>
          <td class="seat seatAvail"></td>
          <td class="seat seatAvail"></td>
          <td class="seat seatAvail"></td>
          <td class="seat seatAvail"></td>
          <td class="seat seatAvail"></td>
          <td class="seat seatAvail"></td>
          <td class="seat seatAvail"></td>
          <td class="seat seatAvail"></td>
          <td class="seat seatAvail"></td>
          <td class="seat seatAvail"></td>
          <td class="seat seatAvail"></td>
          <td class="seat seatAvail"></td>
          <td class="seat seatAvail"></td>
          <td class="seat seatAvail"></td>
          <td class="seat seatAvail"></td>
          <td class="seat seatAvail"></td>
          <td class="seat seatAvail"></td>
          <td class="seat seatAvail"></td>
          <td class="seat seatAvail"></td>
          <td class="seat seatAvail"></td>
          <td class="seat seatAvail"></td>
          <td class="seat seatAvail"></td>
          <td class="seat seatAvail"></td>
          <td class="seat seatAvail"></td>  
        </tr>
        <tr class="rowCadeiras">
          <td class="seat seatAvail"></td>
          <td class="seat seatAvail"></td>
          <td class="seat seatAvail"></td>
          <td class="seat seatAvail"></td>
          <td class="seat seatAvail"></td>
          <td class="seat seatAvail"></td>
          <td class="seat seatAvail"></td>
          <td class="seat seatAvail"></td>
          <td class="seat seatAvail"></td>
          <td class="seat seatAvail"></td>
          <td class="seat seatAvail"></td>
          <td class="seat seatAvail"></td>
          <td class="seat seatAvail"></td>
          <td class="seat seatAvail"></td>
          <td class="seat seatAvail"></td>
          <td class="seat seatAvail"></td> 
          <td class="seat seatAvail"></td>
          <td class="seat seatAvail"></td>
          <td class="seat seatAvail"></td>
          <td class="seat seatAvail"></td>
          <td class="seat seatAvail"></td>
          <td class="seat seatAvail"></td>
          <td class="seat seatAvail"></td>
          <td class="seat seatAvail"></td>
          <td class="seat seatAvail"></td>
          <td class="seat seatAvail"></td>
          <td class="seat seatAvail"></td>
          <td class="seat seatAvail"></td>
          <td class="seat seatAvail"></td>
          <td class="seat seatAvail"></td>
          <td class="seat seatAvail"></td>
          <td class="seat seatAvail"></td>
          <td class="seat seatAvail"></td>
          <td class="seat seatAvail"></td>
          <td class="seat seatAvail"></td>
          <td class="seat seatAvail"></td>
          <td class="seat seatAvail"></td>
          <td class="seat seatAvail"></td>
          <td class="seat seatAvail"></td>
          <td class="seat seatAvail"></td>
          <td class="seat seatAvail"></td>
          <td class="seat seatAvail"></td>
          <td class="seat seatAvail"></td>
          <td class="seat seatAvail"></td>
          <td class="seat seatAvail"></td>
          <td class="seat seatAvail"></td>
          <td class="seat seatAvail"></td>
          <td class="seat seatAvail"></td>
          <td class="seat seatAvail"></td>
          <td class="seat seatAvail"></td>
          <td class="seat seatAvail"></td>
          <td class="seat seatAvail"></td>
          <td class="seat seatAvail"></td>
          <td class="seat seatAvail"></td>
          <td class="seat seatAvail"></td>
          <td class="seat seatAvail"></td>
          <td class="seat seatAvail"></td>
          <td class="seat seatAvail"></td>
          <td class="seat seatAvail"></td>
          <td class="seat seatAvail"></td>
          <td class="seat seatAvail"></td>
          <td class="seat seatAvail"></td>
          <td class="seat seatAvail"></td>
          <td class="seat seatAvail"></td>
          <td class="seat seatAvail"></td>
          <td class="seat seatAvail"></td>
          <td class="seat seatAvail"></td>  
        </tr>
      </table>
    </div>
   </div>
    <div id="fixed-Right">
      <div class="filas">
        <ul>
          <li>10</li>
          <li>11</li>
          <li>12</li>
          <li>13</li>
          <li>14</li>
          <li>15</li>
          <li>16</li>
          <li>17</li>
          <li>18</li>
          <li>19</li>
          <li>20</li>
          <li>21</li>
          <li>22</li>
          <li>23</li>
          <li>24</li>
          <li>25</li>
          <li>26</li>
          <li>27</li>
          <li>28</li>
          <li>29</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="faded-Right"></div>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I made a fiddle for you: http://jsfiddle.net/0m38c89c/.  I'm not sure I understand your problem.  Do you want to set a minimum size for the table and have it scroll when it's smaller than that size?

Comment: Hello @BarbaraLaird, thanks for your quick response and the fiddle :) I want to have a Responsive scrollable table. When I resize the browser window, I want to have a scrollbar in the "fluid" div and not in the browser. something like this.

[link]http://www.456bereastreet.com/lab/responsive-scrollable-tables

Comment: Do you want something like that: http://jsfiddle.net/y3ytp117/

Comment: But when the content of the table (the squares) is bigger than the fluid div I want also to have a scrollbar.  when I resize the browser window, the fluid div becomes smaller but the scrollbar is always there....

Comment: YES, @SteffiA. :D Want do you did?

Answer (score 0):

First add `div` elements to your table cells and apply your `seat` styles to them. Fixed dimension settings don't work for table cells.

Then adapt your `fluid` styles like this:

```
.fluid {
    height: 340px;
    background: #fff;
    width: 100%;
    overflow-x: scroll;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 0 30px;
}
```

Scroll horizontal (overflow-x) and add some space (padding) for your row numbers.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/y3ytp117/)

**Edit:**

Panel height grows with content ([Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/y3ytp117/5/)):

```css
* {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
     -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
          box-sizing: border-box;
}

.left {float: left;}
.right {float: right;}

.clearfix:before,
.clearfix:after{
    content: " ";
    display: table;
}

.clearfix:after {
  clear: both;
}

body {
    background: #F0F0F0;
}

.container, .wrap {
    position: relative;
    max-width: 800px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.container {
    background: #fff;
    height: 100%;
}

.numbers {
    width: 30px;
}

.fader {
    width: 20px;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 100;
}

.fluid, .cadeiras {
    height: 100%;
}

.fluid {
    padding: 0 30px;
}

.cadeiras {
    overflow-x: scroll;
}

.inner {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 10px 20px;
}

#faded-Left {
    left: 30px;
    /* IE9 SVG, needs conditional override of 'filter' to 'none' */
    background: url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,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);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(left, rgba(255,255,255,1) 0%, rgba(255,255,255,0) 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right top, color-stop(0%, rgba(255,255,255,1)), color-stop(100%, rgba(255,255,255,0))); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, rgba(255,255,255,1) 0%, rgba(255,255,255,0) 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(left, rgba(255,255,255,1) 0%, rgba(255,255,255,0) 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(left, rgba(255,255,255,1) 0%, rgba(255,255,255,0) 100%); /* IE10+ */
    background: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(255,255,255,1) 0%, rgba(255,255,255,0) 100%); /* W3C */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#ffffff', endColorstr='#00ffffff', GradientType=1 ); /* IE6-8 */
}

#faded-Right {
    right: 30px;
    /* IE9 SVG, needs conditional override of 'filter' to 'none' */
    background: url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,PD94bWwgdmVyc2lvbj0iMS4wIiA/Pgo8c3ZnIHhtbG5zPSJodHRwOi8vd3d3LnczLm9yZy8yMDAwL3N2ZyIgd2lkdGg9IjEwMCUiIGhlaWdodD0iMTAwJSIgdmlld0JveD0iMCAwIDEgMSIgcHJlc2VydmVBc3BlY3RSYXRpbz0ibm9uZSI+CiAgPGxpbmVhckdyYWRpZW50IGlkPSJncmFkLXVjZ2ctZ2VuZXJhdGVkIiBncmFkaWVudFVuaXRzPSJ1c2VyU3BhY2VPblVzZSIgeDE9IjAlIiB5MT0iMCUiIHgyPSIxMDAlIiB5Mj0iMCUiPgogICAgPHN0b3Agb2Zmc2V0PSIwJSIgc3RvcC1jb2xvcj0iI2ZmZmZmZiIgc3RvcC1vcGFjaXR5PSIxIi8+CiAgICA8c3RvcCBvZmZzZXQ9IjEwMCUiIHN0b3AtY29sb3I9IiNmZmZmZmYiIHN0b3Atb3BhY2l0eT0iMCIvPgogIDwvbGluZWFyR3JhZGllbnQ+CiAgPHJlY3QgeD0iMCIgeT0iMCIgd2lkdGg9IjEiIGhlaWdodD0iMSIgZmlsbD0idXJsKCNncmFkLXVjZ2ctZ2VuZXJhdGVkKSIgLz4KPC9zdmc+);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(right, rgba(255,255,255,1) 0%, rgba(255,255,255,0) 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, right top, right top, color-stop(0%, rgba(255,255,255,1)), color-stop(100%, rgba(255,255,255,0))); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(right, rgba(255,255,255,1) 0%, rgba(255,255,255,0) 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(right, rgba(255,255,255,1) 0%, rgba(255,255,255,0) 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(right, rgba(255,255,255,1) 0%, rgba(255,255,255,0) 100%); /* IE10+ */
    background: linear-gradient(to left, rgba(255,255,255,1) 0%, rgba(255,255,255,0) 100%); /* W3C */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#ffffff', endColorstr='#00ffffff', GradientType=1 ); /* IE6-8 */
}

.imgRelvado {
    height: 40px;
    line-height: 40px;
    background: #04b46b;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.filas {
    display: block;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 11px;
    color: #333;
}
.filas ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 10px;
    list-style: none;
    font-size: 12px;
    height: auto;
}
.filas ul li {
    height: 15px;
    font-weight: bold;
    list-style: none;
}

.seat div {
    height: 11px !important;
    width: 11px !important;
    font-size: 9px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
    -moz-border-radius: 3px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    text-shadow: none!important;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.seatAvail div {
    background: #05cd7a;
    color: #000;
}
.seatTaken div {
    background: #dbdbdb;
    color: #000;
    border: 1px solid #333333;
}
.seatReserv {
    background: #858585;
    color: #000;
    border: 1px solid #5b5b5b;
}
.seatSelect {
    background: #f5c226;
    color: #000;
    border: 1px solid #333333;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="imgRelvado">Relvado</div>
  <div class="container clearfix">
    <div id="fixed-Left" class="numbers left">
      <div class="filas">
        <ul><li>10</li><li>11</li><li>12</li><li>13</li><li>14</li><li>15</li><li>16</li></ul>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="faded-Left" class="fader left">&nbsp;</div>
    <div id="fixed-Right" class="numbers right">
      <div class="filas">
        <ul><li>10</li><li>11</li><li>12</li><li>13</li><li>14</li><li>15</li><li>16</li></ul>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="faded-Right" class="fader right">&nbsp;</div>
    <div class="fluid clearfix">
      <div class="cadeiras">
        <div class="inner">
          <table>
            <tr class="rowCadeiras"><td class="seat seatTaken"><div></div></td><td class="seat seatAvail"><div></div></td><td class="seat seatAvail"><div></div></td><td class="seat seatAvail"><div></div></td><td class="seat seatAvail"><div></div></td><td class="seat seatAvail"><div></div></td><td class="seat seatAvail"><div></div></td><td class="seat seatAvail"><div></div></td><td class="seat seatAvail"><div></div></td><td class="seat seatAvail"><div></div></td><td class="seat seatAvail"><div></div></td><td class="seat seatAvail"><div></div></td><td class="seat seatAvail"><div></div></td><td class="seat seatAvail"><div></div></td><td class="seat seatAvail"><div></div></td><td class="seat seatAvail"><div></div></td><td class="seat seatAvail"><div></div></td><td class="seat seatAvail"><div></div></td><td class="seat seatAvail"><div></div></td><td class="seat seatAvail"><div></div></td><td class="seat seatAvail"><div></div></td><td class="seat seatAvail"><div></div></td><td class="seat seatAvail"><div></div></td><td class="seat seatAvail"><div></div></td><td class="seat seatAvail"><div></div></td><td class="seat seatAvail"><div></div></td><td class="seat seatAvail"><div></div></td><td class="seat seatAvail"><div></div></td><td class="seat seatAvail"><div></div></td><td class="seat seatAvail"><div></div></td><td class="seat seatAvail"><div></div></td><td class="seat seatAvail"><div></div></td><td class="seat seatAvail"><div></div></td><td class="seat seatAvail"><div></div></td><td class="seat seatAvail"><div></div></td><td class="seat seatAvail"><div></div></td><td class="seat seatAvail"><div></div></td><td class="seat seatAvail"><div></div></td><td class="seat seatAvail"><div></div></td><td class="seat seatAvail"><div></div></td><td class="seat seatAvail"><div></div></td><td class="seat seatAvail"><div></div></td><td class="seat seatAvail"><div></div></td><td class="seat seatAvail"><div></div></td><td class="seat seatAvail"><div></div></td><td class="seat seatAvail"><div></div></td><td class="seat seatAvail"><div></div></td><td class="seat seatAvail"><div></div></td><td class="seat seatAvail"><div></div></td><td class="seat seatAvail"><div></div></td><td class="seat seatAvail"><div></div></td><td class="seat seatAvail"><div></div></td><td class="seat seatAvail"><div></div></td><td class="seat seatAvail"><div></div></td><td class="seat seatAvail"><div></div></td><td class="seat seatAvail"><div></div></td><td class="seat seatAvail"><div></div></td><td class="seat seatAvail"><div></div></td><td class="seat seatAvail"><div></div></td><td class="seat seatAvail"><div></div></td><td class="seat seatAvail"><div></div></td><td class="seat seatAvail"><div></div></td><td class="seat seatAvail"><div></div></td><td class="seat seatAvail"><div></div></td><td class="seat seatAvail"><div></div></td><td class="seat seatAvail"><div></div></td><td class="seat seatAvail"><div></div></td></tr>
           <tr class="rowCadeiras"><td class="seat seatTaken"><div></div></td><td class="seat seatAvail"><div></div></td><td class="seat seatAvail"><div></div></td><td class="seat seatAvail"><div></div></td><td class="seat seatAvail"><div></div></td><td class="seat seatAvail"><div></div></td><td class="seat seatAvail"><div></div></td><td class="seat seatAvail"><div></div></td><td class="seat seatAvail"><div></div></td><td class="seat seatAvail"><div></div></td><td class="seat seatAvail"><div></div></td><td class="seat seatAvail"><div></div></td><td class="seat seatAvail"><div></div></td><td class="seat seatAvail"><div></div></td><td class="seat seatAvail"><div></div></td><td class="seat seatAvail"><div></div></td><td class="seat seatAvail"><div></div></td><td class="seat seatAvail"><div></div></td><td class="seat seatAvail"><div></div></td><td class="seat seatAvail"><div></div></td><td class="seat seatAvail"><div></div></td><td class="seat seatAvail"><div></div></td><td class="seat seatAvail"><div></div></td><td class="seat seatAvail"><div></div></td><td class="seat seatAvail"><div></div></td><td class="seat seatAvail"><div></div></td><td class="seat seatAvail"><div></div></td><td class="seat seatAvail"><div></div></td><td class="seat seatAvail"><div></div></td><td class="seat seatAvail"><div></div></td><td class="seat seatAvail"><div></div></td><td class="seat seatAvail"><div></div></td><td class="seat seatAvail"><div></div></td><td class="seat seatAvail"><div></div></td><td class="seat seatAvail"><div></div></td><td class="seat seatAvail"><div></div></td><td class="seat seatAvail"><div></div></td><td class="seat seatAvail"><div></div></td><td class="seat seatAvail"><div></div></td><td class="seat seatAvail"><div></div></td><td class="seat seatAvail"><div></div></td><td class="seat seatAvail"><div></div></td><td class="seat seatAvail"><div></div></td><td class="seat seatAvail"><div></div></td><td class="seat seatAvail"><div></div></td><td class="seat seatAvail"><div></div></td><td class="seat seatAvail"><div></div></td><td class="seat seatAvail"><div></div></td><td class="seat seatAvail"><div></div></td><td class="seat seatAvail"><div></div></td><td class="seat seatAvail"><div></div></td><td class="seat seatAvail"><div></div></td><td class="seat seatAvail"><div></div></td><td class="seat seatAvail"><div></div></td><td class="seat seatAvail"><div></div></td><td class="seat seatAvail"><div></div></td><td class="seat seatAvail"><div></div></td><td class="seat seatAvail"><div></div></td><td class="seat seatAvail"><div></div></td><td class="seat seatAvail"><div></div></td><td class="seat seatAvail"><div></div></td><td class="seat seatAvail"><div></div></td><td class="seat seatAvail"><div></div></td><td class="seat seatAvail"><div></div></td><td class="seat seatAvail"><div></div></td><td class="seat seatAvail"><div></div></td><td class="seat seatAvail"><div></div></td></tr>
           <tr class="rowCadeiras"><td class="seat seatTaken"><div></div></td><td class="seat seatAvail"><div></div></td><td class="seat seatAvail"><div></div></td><td class="seat seatAvail"><div></div></td><td class="seat seatAvail"><div></div></td><td class="seat seatAvail"><div></div></td><td class="seat seatAvail"><div></div></td><td class="seat seatAvail"><div></div></td><td class="seat seatAvail"><div></div></td><td class="seat seatAvail"><div></div></td><td class="seat seatAvail"><div></div></td><td class="seat seatAvail"><div></div></td><td class="seat seatAvail"><div></div></td><td class="seat seatAvail"><div></div></td><td class="seat seatAvail"><div></div></td><td class="seat seatAvail"><div></div></td><td class="seat seatAvail"><div></div></td><td class="seat seatAvail"><div></div></td><td class="seat seatAvail"><div></div></td><td class="seat seatAvail"><div></div></td><td class="seat seatAvail"><div></div></td><td class="seat seatAvail"><div></div></td><td class="seat seatAvail"><div></div></td><td class="seat seatAvail"><div></div></td><td class="seat seatAvail"><div></div></td><td class="seat seatAvail"><div></div></td><td class="seat seatAvail"><div></div></td><td class="seat seatAvail"><div></div></td><td class="seat seatAvail"><div></div></td><td class="seat seatAvail"><div></div></td><td class="seat seatAvail"><div></div></td><td class="seat seatAvail"><div></div></td><td class="seat seatAvail"><div></div></td><td class="seat seatAvail"><div></div></td><td class="seat seatAvail"><div></div></td><td class="seat seatAvail"><div></div></td><td class="seat seatAvail"><div></div></td><td class="seat seatAvail"><div></div></td><td class="seat seatAvail"><div></div></td><td class="seat seatAvail"><div></div></td><td class="seat seatAvail"><div></div></td><td class="seat seatAvail"><div></div></td><td class="seat seatAvail"><div></div></td><td class="seat seatAvail"><div></div></td><td class="seat seatAvail"><div></div></td><td class="seat seatAvail"><div></div></td><td class="seat seatAvail"><div></div></td><td class="seat seatAvail"><div></div></td><td class="seat seatAvail"><div></div></td><td class="seat seatAvail"><div></div></td><td class="seat seatAvail"><div></div></td><td class="seat seatAvail"><div></div></td><td class="seat seatAvail"><div></div></td><td class="seat seatAvail"><div></div></td><td class="seat seatAvail"><div></div></td><td class="seat seatAvail"><div></div></td><td class="seat seatAvail"><div></div></td><td class="seat seatAvail"><div></div></td><td class="seat seatAvail"><div></div></td><td class="seat seatAvail"><div></div></td><td class="seat seatAvail"><div></div></td><td class="seat seatAvail"><div></div></td><td class="seat seatAvail"><div></div></td><td class="seat seatAvail"><div></div></td><td class="seat seatAvail"><div></div></td><td class="seat seatAvail"><div></div></td><td class="seat seatAvail"><div></div></td></tr>
           <tr class="rowCadeiras"><td class="seat seatTaken"><div></div></td><td class="seat seatAvail"><div></div></td><td class="seat seatAvail"><div></div></td><td class="seat seatAvail"><div></div></td><td class="seat seatAvail"><div></div></td><td class="seat seatAvail"><div></div></td><td class="seat seatAvail"><div></div></td><td class="seat seatAvail"><div></div></td><td class="seat seatAvail"><div></div></td><td class="seat seatAvail"><div></div></td><td class="seat seatAvail"><div></div></td><td class="seat seatAvail"><div></div></td><td class="seat seatAvail"><div></div></td><td class="seat seatAvail"><div></div></td><td class="seat seatAvail"><div></div></td><td class="seat seatAvail"><div></div></td><td class="seat seatAvail"><div></div></td><td class="seat seatAvail"><div></div></td><td class="seat seatAvail"><div></div></td><td class="seat seatAvail"><div></div></td><td class="seat seatAvail"><div></div></td><td class="seat seatAvail"><div></div></td><td class="seat seatAvail"><div></div></td><td class="seat seatAvail"><div></div></td><td class="seat seatAvail"><div></div></td><td class="seat seatAvail"><div></div></td><td class="seat seatAvail"><div></div></td><td class="seat seatAvail"><div></div></td><td class="seat seatAvail"><div></div></td><td class="seat seatAvail"><div></div></td><td class="seat seatAvail"><div></div></td><td class="seat seatAvail"><div></div></td><td class="seat seatAvail"><div></div></td><td class="seat seatAvail"><div></div></td><td class="seat seatAvail"><div></div></td><td class="seat seatAvail"><div></div></td><td class="seat seatAvail"><div></div></td><td class="seat seatAvail"><div></div></td><td class="seat seatAvail"><div></div></td><td class="seat seatAvail"><div></div></td><td class="seat seatAvail"><div></div></td><td class="seat seatAvail"><div></div></td><td class="seat seatAvail"><div></div></td><td class="seat seatAvail"><div></div></td><td class="seat seatAvail"><div></div></td><td class="seat seatAvail"><div></div></td><td class="seat seatAvail"><div></div></td><td class="seat seatAvail"><div></div></td><td class="seat seatAvail"><div></div></td><td class="seat seatAvail"><div></div></td><td class="seat seatAvail"><div></div></td><td class="seat seatAvail"><div></div></td><td class="seat seatAvail"><div></div></td><td class="seat seatAvail"><div></div></td><td class="seat seatAvail"><div></div></td><td class="seat seatAvail"><div></div></td><td class="seat seatAvail"><div></div></td><td class="seat seatAvail"><div></div></td><td class="seat seatAvail"><div></div></td><td class="seat seatAvail"><div></div></td><td class="seat seatAvail"><div></div></td><td class="seat seatAvail"><div></div></td><td class="seat seatAvail"><div></div></td><td class="seat seatAvail"><div></div></td><td class="seat seatAvail"><div></div></td><td class="seat seatAvail"><div></div></td><td class="seat seatAvail"><div></div></td></tr>
           <tr class="rowCadeiras"><td class="seat seatTaken"><div></div></td><td class="seat seatAvail"><div></div></td><td class="seat seatAvail"><div></div></td><td class="seat seatAvail"><div></div></td><td class="seat seatAvail"><div></div></td><td class="seat seatAvail"><div></div></td><td class="seat seatAvail"><div></div></td><td class="seat seatAvail"><div></div></td><td class="seat seatAvail"><div></div></td><td class="seat seatAvail"><div></div></td><td class="seat seatAvail"><div></div></td><td class="seat seatAvail"><div></div></td><td class="seat seatAvail"><div></div></td><td class="seat seatAvail"><div></div></td><td class="seat seatAvail"><div></div></td><td class="seat seatAvail"><div></div></td><td class="seat seatAvail"><div></div></td><td class="seat seatAvail"><div></div></td><td class="seat seatAvail"><div></div></td><td class="seat seatAvail"><div></div></td><td class="seat seatAvail"><div></div></td><td class="seat seatAvail"><div></div></td><td class="seat seatAvail"><div></div></td><td class="seat seatAvail"><div></div></td><td class="seat seatAvail"><div></div></td><td class="seat seatAvail"><div></div></td><td class="seat seatAvail"><div></div></td><td class="seat seatAvail"><div></div></td><td class="seat seatAvail"><div></div></td><td class="seat seatAvail"><div></div></td><td class="seat seatAvail"><div></div></td><td class="seat seatAvail"><div></div></td><td class="seat seatAvail"><div></div></td><td class="seat seatAvail"><div></div></td><td class="seat seatAvail"><div></div></td><td class="seat seatAvail"><div></div></td><td class="seat seatAvail"><div></div></td><td class="seat seatAvail"><div></div></td><td class="seat seatAvail"><div></div></td><td class="seat seatAvail"><div></div></td><td class="seat seatAvail"><div></div></td><td class="seat seatAvail"><div></div></td><td class="seat seatAvail"><div></div></td><td class="seat seatAvail"><div></div></td><td class="seat seatAvail"><div></div></td><td class="seat seatAvail"><div></div></td><td class="seat seatAvail"><div></div></td><td class="seat seatAvail"><div></div></td><td class="seat seatAvail"><div></div></td><td class="seat seatAvail"><div></div></td><td class="seat seatAvail"><div></div></td><td class="seat seatAvail"><div></div></td><td class="seat seatAvail"><div></div></td><td class="seat seatAvail"><div></div></td><td class="seat seatAvail"><div></div></td><td class="seat seatAvail"><div></div></td><td class="seat seatAvail"><div></div></td><td class="seat seatAvail"><div></div></td><td class="seat seatAvail"><div></div></td><td class="seat seatAvail"><div></div></td><td class="seat seatAvail"><div></div></td><td class="seat seatAvail"><div></div></td><td class="seat seatAvail"><div></div></td><td class="seat seatAvail"><div></div></td><td class="seat seatAvail"><div></div></td><td class="seat seatAvail"><div></div></td><td class="seat seatAvail"><div></div></td></tr>
           <tr class="rowCadeiras"><td class="seat seatTaken"><div></div></td><td class="seat seatAvail"><div></div></td><td class="seat seatAvail"><div></div></td><td class="seat seatAvail"><div></div></td><td class="seat seatAvail"><div></div></td><td class="seat seatAvail"><div></div></td><td class="seat seatAvail"><div></div></td><td class="seat seatAvail"><div></div></td><td class="seat seatAvail"><div></div></td><td class="seat seatAvail"><div></div></td><td class="seat seatAvail"><div></div></td><td class="seat seatAvail"><div></div></td><td class="seat seatAvail"><div></div></td><td class="seat seatAvail"><div></div></td><td class="seat seatAvail"><div></div></td><td class="seat seatAvail"><div></div></td><td class="seat seatAvail"><div></div></td><td class="seat seatAvail"><div></div></td><td class="seat seatAvail"><div></div></td><td class="seat seatAvail"><div></div></td><td class="seat seatAvail"><div></div></td><td class="seat seatAvail"><div></div></td><td class="seat seatAvail"><div></div></td><td class="seat seatAvail"><div></div></td><td class="seat seatAvail"><div></div></td><td class="seat seatAvail"><div></div></td><td class="seat seatAvail"><div></div></td><td class="seat seatAvail"><div></div></td><td class="seat seatAvail"><div></div></td><td class="seat seatAvail"><div></div></td><td class="seat seatAvail"><div></div></td><td class="seat seatAvail"><div></div></td><td class="seat seatAvail"><div></div></td><td class="seat seatAvail"><div></div></td><td class="seat seatAvail"><div></div></td><td class="seat seatAvail"><div></div></td><td class="seat seatAvail"><div></div></td><td class="seat seatAvail"><div></div></td><td class="seat seatAvail"><div></div></td><td class="seat seatAvail"><div></div></td><td class="seat seatAvail"><div></div></td><td class="seat seatAvail"><div></div></td><td class="seat seatAvail"><div></div></td><td class="seat seatAvail"><div></div></td><td class="seat seatAvail"><div></div></td><td class="seat seatAvail"><div></div></td><td class="seat seatAvail"><div></div></td><td class="seat seatAvail"><div></div></td><td class="seat seatAvail"><div></div></td><td class="seat seatAvail"><div></div></td><td class="seat seatAvail"><div></div></td><td class="seat seatAvail"><div></div></td><td class="seat seatAvail"><div></div></td><td class="seat seatAvail"><div></div></td><td class="seat seatAvail"><div></div></td><td class="seat seatAvail"><div></div></td><td class="seat seatAvail"><div></div></td><td class="seat seatAvail"><div></div></td><td class="seat seatAvail"><div></div></td><td class="seat seatAvail"><div></div></td><td class="seat seatAvail"><div></div></td><td class="seat seatAvail"><div></div></td><td class="seat seatAvail"><div></div></td><td class="seat seatAvail"><div></div></td><td class="seat seatAvail"><div></div></td><td class="seat seatAvail"><div></div></td><td class="seat seatAvail"><div></div></td></tr>
           <tr class="rowCadeiras"><td class="seat seatTaken"><div></div></td><td class="seat seatAvail"><div></div></td><td class="seat seatAvail"><div></div></td><td class="seat seatAvail"><div></div></td><td class="seat seatAvail"><div></div></td><td class="seat seatAvail"><div></div></td><td class="seat seatAvail"><div></div></td><td class="seat seatAvail"><div></div></td><td class="seat seatAvail"><div></div></td><td class="seat seatAvail"><div></div></td><td class="seat seatAvail"><div></div></td><td class="seat seatAvail"><div></div></td><td class="seat seatAvail"><div></div></td><td class="seat seatAvail"><div></div></td><td class="seat seatAvail"><div></div></td><td class="seat seatAvail"><div></div></td><td class="seat seatAvail"><div></div></td><td class="seat seatAvail"><div></div></td><td class="seat seatAvail"><div></div></td><td class="seat seatAvail"><div></div></td><td class="seat seatAvail"><div></div></td><td class="seat seatAvail"><div></div></td><td class="seat seatAvail"><div></div></td><td class="seat seatAvail"><div></div></td><td class="seat seatAvail"><div></div></td><td class="seat seatAvail"><div></div></td><td class="seat seatAvail"><div></div></td><td class="seat seatAvail"><div></div></td><td class="seat seatAvail"><div></div></td><td class="seat seatAvail"><div></div></td><td class="seat seatAvail"><div></div></td><td class="seat seatAvail"><div></div></td><td class="seat seatAvail"><div></div></td><td class="seat seatAvail"><div></div></td><td class="seat seatAvail"><div></div></td><td class="seat seatAvail"><div></div></td><td class="seat seatAvail"><div></div></td><td class="seat seatAvail"><div></div></td><td class="seat seatAvail"><div></div></td><td class="seat seatAvail"><div></div></td><td class="seat seatAvail"><div></div></td><td class="seat seatAvail"><div></div></td><td class="seat seatAvail"><div></div></td><td class="seat seatAvail"><div></div></td><td class="seat seatAvail"><div></div></td><td class="seat seatAvail"><div></div></td><td class="seat seatAvail"><div></div></td><td class="seat seatAvail"><div></div></td><td class="seat seatAvail"><div></div></td><td class="seat seatAvail"><div></div></td><td class="seat seatAvail"><div></div></td><td class="seat seatAvail"><div></div></td><td class="seat seatAvail"><div></div></td><td class="seat seatAvail"><div></div></td><td class="seat seatAvail"><div></div></td><td class="seat seatAvail"><div></div></td><td class="seat seatAvail"><div></div></td><td class="seat seatAvail"><div></div></td><td class="seat seatAvail"><div></div></td><td class="seat seatAvail"><div></div></td><td class="seat seatAvail"><div></div></td><td class="seat seatAvail"><div></div></td><td class="seat seatAvail"><div></div></td><td class="seat seatAvail"><div></div></td><td class="seat seatAvail"><div></div></td><td class="seat seatAvail"><div></div></td><td class="seat seatAvail"><div></div></td></tr>
          </table>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much, @SteffiA You are the best. I have another problem. I can't see the last two colums of seats. (there is three grey seats and I see only one...)  I try to change the width in Fluid div to max-width: 770px; but when I resize the browser and do scroll I can´t see them either.  I want the scroll only in fluid div but it seems to affect the filas divs also. Any ideias? thanks for the help .

[link]https://jsfiddle.net/y3ytp117/1/

Comment: @PauloFrutuoso You're completely right. Sorry for that. The problems are the fader elements. You have to add some padding to the inner element to show the first/last elements and you even have to add some more to enable clicking on the very first/last elements. Looks not very nice (because of the large gap), but works. Try this: [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/y3ytp117/2/).

Comment: no need to apologize. that's perfect. Thank you one more time. I have one more issue to ask you if you don't mind. How can I expand the div's height of the white content (container, fluid or cadeiras, I don't know witch one) automatically when I fill up with seats. I try to put 100% or auto in container DIV but the div disappears. thanks

https://jsfiddle.net/y3ytp117/2/

Comment: here's the fiddle to show you the idea. I put the faded div's 100% and the fixed auto.

https://jsfiddle.net/pfrutuoso/y3ytp117/4/

Comment: You're simply the best @SteffiA. thanks you so much for the support.